# Ubuntu 22.04.3 server still installs a 5.15 kernel, not 5.19

Tags: server, kernel, 22.04

To access AMX hardware instructions on Intel Sapphire Rapids CPUs you need to be running Linux kernel 5.16 or later. To use many popular hardware drivers you have to run a 5.x series kernel, since many hardware vendors haven't yet built drivers for 6.x kernels. For this reason I'd like to install a 5.19 kernel and get 5.19 kernel updates as they are released.

A few weeks ago the [Ubuntu kernel lifecycle](https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle) page listed the 22.04.2 image as coming with a 5.19 kernel by default. Ubuntu kernel lifecycle page on 2023-08-10:

[image: Ubuntu kernel lifecycle page on 2023-08-10]

However, if you install 22.04.2-server you get a 5.15 kernel, not 5.19. If you install the HWE kernel package `linux-generic-hwe-22.04` you get a 6.2 kernel, not 5.19.

```
support@ubuntu22042:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu22042 5.15.0-78-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 7 15:25:09 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Today the [Ubuntu kernel lifecycle](https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle) page lists 22.04.3 as coming with a 5.19 kernel by default, and the page removed the listing for 22.04.2 entirely. Ubuntu kernel lifecycle page on 2023-08-16:

[image: Ubuntu kernel lifecycle page on 2023-08-16]

However, if you install 22.04.3-server you get a 5.15 kernel, not 5.19:

```
support@ubuntu22043:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu22043 5.15.0-79-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 10 16:07:21 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If you install the HWE kernel package `linux-generic-hwe-22.04` you get a 6.2 kernel.

There is a difference between 22.04.3-server and 22.04.3-desktop. If I install the 22.04.3-desktop ISO I get a 6.2 kernel with a default install:

```
support@ubuntu220403-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu220403-desktop 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There are 5.19 kernel packages in the Ubuntu repo for 22.04. I can see them when I run `apt-cache search 5.19 | grep generic`. I can even install a specific 5.19 kernel by running:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic
```

However, that locks my kernel on 5.19.0-46, and even though 5.19.0-50 is available, `apt-get upgrade` won't update the kernel. I won't get patches automatically for 5.19.

**What package do I need to install on 22.04.3-server to get a 5.19 kernel, as shown on the [Ubuntu kernel lifecycle](https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle) page, that will continue to get updates and patches for 5.19 as they are released?**

Comment: I think that graphic is wrong. I believe 22.04.2 had HWE kernel 5.19 and 22.04.3 has HWE kernel 6.2. I don't think you can choose to stay on HWE 5.19. Either, you stay on 5.15 LTS kernel, or you follow the HWE kernels, which are bumped at each point release.

Comment: Why would you want the 5.19 kernel that is *unsupported* being from Ubuntu 22.10 which is EOL.   Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using HWE upgraded to 6.2 which is a supported kernel (*coming from 23.04 which is supported*) as its replacement.  The GA kernel stack (*default for servers as most stable option*) is supported for the life of the product, or you can use HWE which changes roughly six monthly for the first two years of the project as outlined at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu.com/issues/13092   (*though even ignoring the minor error, the small window of orange-coverage of 5.19 (22.04.3 should say 6.2) shows you're talking about 6 months only of coverage; 5.19 already ended; 6.2 now the supported HWE kernel*)

Comment: Artur: I think the graphic is wrong too, but if you google "Ubuntu 22.04 5.19" you'll find a dozen articles from web sites devoted to covering Linux stating that Ubuntu is switching to 5.19 as the stock LTS kernel (not HWE) for 22.04.2 onwards. I believe that information/announcement came from Canonical and it's backed up by the Ubuntu Kernel Lifecycle page, which stated that both 22.04.2 and 22.04.3 ship with 5.19. It makes some sense because the new AWX instructions in Intel Sapphire Rapids can only be utilized if you're running a 5.16 (or later) kernel, not 5.15.

Comment: guiverc: To access AMX hardware instructions on Intel Sapphire Rapids CPUs you need to be running Linux kernel 5.16 or later. To use many popular hardware drivers you have to run a 5.x series kernel, since many hardware vendors haven't yet built drivers for 6.x kernels. For this reason I'd like to install a 5.19 kernel and get 5.19 kernel updates as they are released.

Comment: I dispute "*believe that information/announcement came from Canonical*".  I'm on the Ubuntu News team, and thus am involved in re-posting some (ML)  articles to some ubuntu.com sites and I've never seen any. Yes the link you provided has an error; look in a prior comment and I've filed an issue over that, but if you believe the detail is elsewhere please provide some detail, as I used "*Ubuntu 22.04 5.19*" in a search and found nothing of *quality* that made any reference to that; or wasn't easily seen as temporary fitting normal HWE behavior for kernels.  I'm not a Canonical employee.

Answer (score 5):

The graphic has misled you.

Ubuntu Server 22.04 defaults to the GA (General Availability) kernel 5.15. HWE is optional. GA means that your system will remain on the kernel 5.15 path for the entire life of the release.

Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 defaults to the HWE (Hardware Enablement) kernel, which bumps every six months to match the six-month standard releases of Ubuntu. GA is optional:

```
  LTS      Standard   GA Kernel  HWE Kernel
 22.04                  5.15       5.15
 22.04.1                5.15       5.15
 22.04.2    22.10       5.15       5.19
 22.04.3    23.04       5.15       6.2
 22.04.4    23.10       5.15       TBD
```

Now let's look at your specific case:

There is no path to remain on an Ubuntu-provided 5.19 kernel. You can do so, of course, for as long as it's supported. You can keep using it after it's no longer supported...though obviously that means no support and no security patches and you're accepting risk.

- Oops, 22.10 support ended 20 July 2023, so that 5.19 kernel may soon be gone! Start testing your hardware with the 6.x kernel, and start filing bug reports!

Comment: 23.10 hasn't been released yet.. typo as you meant 22.10 I gather.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that I am misunderstanding the intent of the [Ubuntu Kernel Lifecycle](https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle) page. Although it only lists LTS point releases, it lists the HWE kernel version that was available on the day that the LTS point release was published, **which has nothing to do with what kernel you'll actually get if you install the specific LTS release that's listed.**

If you install the **desktop** version of a release, you won't get a choice of kernel -- you'll automatically get the *current* HWE kernel, **which has nothing to do with the kernel version listed on this page**.

If you install the **server** version of a release you'll have the option of installing the GA kernel version (which is not listed on this page) or the *current* HWE kernel version, **which has nothing to do with the kernel version listed on this page**.

Since HWE follows a rolling update model, the kernel version listed on this page may no longer be available by the time you install a specific release. If you install 22.04.3-desktop today you won't get kernel 5.19, you'll get 6.2, **even though 22.04.3 was only released 6 days ago.**

In short, if you want to know what GA or HWE kernel you're going to get when you install a specific Ubuntu point release, don't bother checking the [Ubuntu Kernel Lifecycle](https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle) page, because it doesn't contain that information.

Comment: Desktop *flavors* provided media of 22.04 that contain both GA & HWE kernel stack; not all use the default of Ubuntu Desktop (ie. HWE for all 22.04 media), eg. if you install Lubuntu 22.04 or 22.04.1 you'll be using the GA kernel stack (like Server media), only 22.04.2 media used the HWE stack as did later media (ie. just as 18.04 & earlier Ubuntu Desktop had); the same applies to Xubuntu too...  You select kernel stack for some *flavors* at download time; with the kernel doc you refer to relating to Ubuntu Desktop (*not all Desktop flavors*)

Comment: If you install 22.04.3-desktop today you won't get kernel 5.19, you'll get 6.2, **because** 22.04.3 was released 6 days ago.